# How to fix: TypeError: fn is not a function while running artillery script

Tags: javascript, async-await, playwright, artillery

I am getting the error `⠇ TypeError: fn is not a function` while running my artillery test file.

Here is the `yml` layout:

```
  target: "https://www.therisecollection.co/"  # Update with your test URL
   # Load the Playwright engine:
  engines:
    playwright: {}
  processor: './javascriptTest.js'
  phases:
    - duration: 60
      arrivalRate: 5
      name: Warm up
    - duration: 120
      arrivalRate: 5
      rampTo: 50
      name: Ramp up load
    - duration: 600
      arrivalRate: 50
      name: Sustained load

scenarios:
  - engine: "playwright"
    flowFunction: 'viewHome'
    flow: []
```

here is the JavaScript I am attempting to use:

```
async function viewHome(page) {
  await page.goto('https://www.therisecollection.co/');
  await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Home' }).click();
  await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'About' }).click();
  await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Home' }).click();
  await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'About' }).click();
  await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Home' }).click();
  await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'About' }).click();
  await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Home' }).click();
  await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'About' }).click();
}

module.export = viewHome;
```

I have seen the following recommended but haven't attempted this yet:

- Run artillery from a different location
- Re-install artillery

What is the best way to begin debugging this issue? From what I can see, everything related to the function is defined correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to export the function as a named export. So:

```js
module.exports = { 
  viewHome 
};
```